# как разобрать json с помощью Rapidjson

Tags: c++, json

Есть json файл:

```
{
    "1":  {"nickname":"demo","rating":2805},
    "2":  {"nickname":"demo2","rating":2795},
    "5":  {"nickname":"mytwelwesign","rating":2795}
}
```

С помощью цикла

```
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = document.MemberonBegin();
        itr != document.MemberonEnd(); ++itr)
{
    // ???
}
```

я могу прочитать значения "первого уровня", а как прочитать значения дальше?

Answer (score 1):

У членов объектов JSON имеются поля `name` и `value`. Соответственно, внутри вашего цикла вы имеете к ним доступ из итератора в виде `itr->name` и `itr->value`.

У значения `value`, если оно `IsObject() == true`, имеются те же возможности для итерации, что и у документа. Соответственно, во вложенном цикле абсолютно так же итерируетесь по членам, как и во внешнем цикле.

Ну или можете сразу по имени свойства JSON обращаться: `itr->value["nickname"].GetString()`, если уверены в содержимом (если не уверены, есть `itr->value.HasMember("nickname")`).

Answer (score 0):

Для конкретно приведенного примера, например, вот так:

```
printf("Content of JSON documnt:\n");
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = document.MemberonBegin();
        itr != document.MemberonEnd(); ++itr)
{
    Value &n = itr->name;
    Value &v = itr->value;

switch (v.GetType())
{
case kObjectType:
    {   // вложеный объект
        printf("[%s]:\n", n.GetString());
        for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator itr2 = document.MemberonBegin();
            itr2 != document.MemberonEnd(); ++itr2)
        {
            Value &n2 = itr2->name;
            Value &v2 = itr2->value;

            switch (v2.GetType())
            {
            case kStringType:
                {
                    printf("-[%s] = \'%s\'\n", n2.GetString(), v2.GetString());
                    break;
                }
            case kNumberType:
                {
                    // допускаем, что у нас только uint'ы
                    // иначе надо делать доп. проверки на тип числа
                    // например: if (v2.IsDouble())
                    if (v2.IsUint())
                    {
                        printf("-[%s] = %u\n", n2.GetString(), v2.GetUint());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Unexpected type for this context. Skip it.\n");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            default:
                printf("Unexpected type for this context. Skip it.\n");
            }
        }
        break;
    }
case kStringType:
    printf("[%s] = %s\n", n.GetString(), v.GetString());
    break;
default:
    printf("Unexpected type for this context. Skip it.\n");
}
}
```